# Generating Context-Free-Grammar (TOC Basics)

Tags: context-free-grammar

The question states:

*Give a context-free grammar that generates the language
    A = {a^i b^j c^k | i=j or j=k where i,j,k >= 0}
Is the grammar ambiguous? Why or why not?*
**[Intro. to TOC Sipser 2.10]**

The book doesn't have too many good examples on how to generate a context free grammar merely from a description of the language.

Should I try creating a pushdown-automata and then try to convert from there? Or is there some general guideline to this thing?

Comment: This doesn't sound much like a question. It sounds more like a demand.  Perhaps you could show your working so far and ask specific questions to help you?

Comment: Didn't mean for it to come out like that. Edited it. Can you help now?

Comment: Start asking such questions on [CSTheory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Just go [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguous_grammar#Inherently_ambiguous_languages) and try to guess if your example is similar (a sarcastic hint: it's the same thing), just try to argument why it is so otherwise it will be just useless..